# fishshell alias without replacing command

Tags: fish

I am having a trial of fishshell, currently using zsh

When I set an alias in fishshell config, e.g.

```
alias aa="abc -d -e -f"
```

Fishshell replaces the command with the actual command while I am typing the command. It is possibile to config it to work seamlessly without replacing the command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're describing is abbreviations, not aliases. Abbreviations are commands that expand as you type them.

Running a command like you described:

```
alias aa="abc -d -e -f"
```

will indeed set an alias that will not expand in-line.

Comment: Thanks, How about after I execute the command. It shows the real command of the alias. Any config could keep the alias command shown instead of the real one?

Comment: @kkpoon, Your question doesn't make sense. As ridiculous_fish pointed out what you're describing are command abbreviations, not aliases. If you don't want the real command to be shown define an alias, not an abbreviation.

Comment: Ah. I get it. Thank for you advise

Comment: After investigation, I found the problem which my command being abbr instead of aliasing. At the beginning, I added abbr settings in my `.config/fish/config.fish` and it installed to somewhere else. While I found that abbr isn't what I want, I removed abbr settings from my `config.fish` and add alias. However, the abbr isn't cleanup completely, the command still works like abbr. Finally, I remove all `.config/fish, .config/omf, .local/share/fish, .local/share/omf`. Everything start over again and the alias works like an alias. Thanks